# this.setState not changing the states value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`ageVSpqiYearPick` is a variable that decides which background layer to select( function `selectBackgroundLayer()`). `ageVSpqiYearPick` gets set when a menu item is selected. With the currenct code, the variable is not being changed by `setState`. `console.log` is:

> 'selectBackgroundLayer:  ,2021'

```
this.state = {   //in constructor
  ageVSpqiYearPick: ''  
};

<MenuItem  //these menu items are located in render method
  key="Age"
  text="Age"
  onClick={() => {
    this.props.selectBackgroundLayer('Age');
    this.setState({ ageVSpqiYearPick: "Age" });
    console.log("Setting AGE"); 
  }}
/>

<MenuItem
  key="PSR"
  text="PQI - Pavement Quality Index"
  onClick={() => {
    this.setState({ ageVSpqiYearPick: 'getPQI' }, () => { this.props.selectBackgroundLayer('getPQI'); });
    console.log("Setting PQI");
  }}
/>
//this is a handling function for a dropdown selector for changing the year
onChangeDropdownPQI = (e) => {  
  const { target } = e;  
  const { name, value } = target;

  console.log("selectBackgroundLayer: " + this.state.ageVSpqiYearPick + " ," + value);
  this.selectBackgroundLayer(this.state.ageVSpqiYearPick,value); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Dotsc Intern. I'm not 100% sure this is working React code... Have you dropped parts of it? Also could you rephrase your question?

Comment: basically i need the ageVSpqi variable to be set to the value of the menu that was selected, either 'pqi' or 'age'. right now, when console.logging, the value is null;

Comment: yes it is partial code, the actual file is almost 2000 lines

Comment: I see you have console.logs in your functions, do they all display a value?

Comment: nope, super weird, they just display whatever they are set to in the state constructor, its as if the setState function is just being skipped over. I ended up having to use two dropdowns each with its own handling function. then hiding the HTMl element depending on the menu item selection

Answer (score 0):

change `onClick` to `onSelect`

```
<MenuItem key="Age" text="Age"
                    onSelect={() => { this.props.selectBackgroundLayer('Age');  this.setState({ ageVSpqiYearPick: "Age" }); console.log("Setting AGE"); }} />

<MenuItem key="PSR" text="PQI - Pavement Quality Index"
                    onSelect={() => { this.setState({ ageVSpqiYearPick: 'getPQI' }, () => { this.props.selectBackgroundLayer('getPQI'); }); console.log("Setting PQI");} } />
```

Comment: When changing to onSelect, the event never registers. No console.log, change state or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Place `this.state = ...` in the constructor like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {ageVSpqiYearPick: ''}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <a href="facebook.com" onClick={
          () => this.setState(
              {ageVSpqiYearPick: 'getPQI'},
              function () {
                console.log(this.state);
              })
          }>Visit facebook.com!</a>

      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Comment: It is already, sorry I wasnt exactly sure what to post the file is 1700 lines